# Convert JSON file to have each set of curly brackets on a single line

Tags: bash, jq

I have a simple JSON file like this:

```
{
  "user_id": 123,
  "value": 99
},
{
  "user_id": 122,
  "value": 100
}
```

but I need it to look like this:

```
{"user_id": 123, "value": 99}
{"user_id": 122, "value": 100}
```

Basically every set of curly brackets should be on its own line. I was hoping it would be simple with jq but I'm quite new to it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Neither of those is a valid JSON file. You need square brackets around everything to make an array of objects, and comma between the objects.

Comment: Most JSON tools don't give you this level of control. You can either ask for pretty-printing, and it will spread the objects across multiple lines, or compact formatting and everything will be on the same line.

Comment: Why do you care, other than esthetics? The first version is quite readable.

Comment: The definition of JSON file usually involves the contents being a stream of one or more valid JSON values, which the latter qualifies as.

Comment: I have inherited a script requiring the latter format and I was hoping not to have to rewrite any of it.

Comment: @Barmar The second is valid [JSONLines](https://jsonlines.org/), which seems to be exactly what the OP wants. And this is perfectly supported by `jq` using `-c`. Having each JSON document take up exactly one line simplifies certain operations on a stream of JSON docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jq` can be used to wrap the input (as raw text) inside `[...]`, with the result being parsable by its builtin `fromjson` filter. Split the resulting array into separate objects again, and use `-c` to output each object on a single line.

```
$ cat old.txt
{
  "user_id": 123,
  "value": 99
},
{
  "user_id": 122,
  "value": 100
} 
$ jq -csR '"[\(.)]" | fromjson |.[]' old.txt
{"user_id":123,"value":99}
{"user_id":122,"value":100}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get rid of the comma between the two objects (which is definitely invalid JSON), then just use jq's `--compact-output` (or `-c`) option and the [identity filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Identity:.) `.`.

```sh
jq --compact-output '.'
```

```json
{"user_id":123,"value":99}
{"user_id":122,"value":100}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/y7V5u_K2V7)